VPN On RaspberryPi Prevents Data Shipping Out from WeeWx
I have a raspberryPi 4 running raspberryPi debian OS and I use it as a weather server with Weewx. This server connects to a gateway that brings in data from my Ecowitt. Last week, I decided to add a VPN to the Pi using nordVPN's CLI and it was working great! I had to whitelist some ports for accessing locahost web interfaces like my plex server but all seemed good. I could still access the web interface for the weewx data as well. About a week later, with the pi still connected to a vpn, I realized the weather data from Weewx was no longer being collected or shipped out to external sources. Even the internal localhost site where I can see the data was available but there was no data in there. What is happening here and what do I need to do to run the VPN and get weewx data at the same time?
Thanks in advance.
I tried looking for info on ports I might need to open or somewhere in the config that might be messed up but nothing has worked yet.

I did some digging because the internet did not have an easy answer and was able to solve this. The NordVPN cli by default disables LAN discovery. I found this simply by doing
$ nordvpn settings
Technology: NORDLYNX
Firewall: enabled
Firewall Mark: 0xe1f1
Routing: enabled
Analytics: enabled
Kill Switch: disabled
Threat Protection Lite: disabled
Notify: disabled
Auto-connect: disabled
IPv6: disabled
Meshnet: enabled
DNS: disabled
LAN Discovery: disabled
Allowlisted ports:
22 -    24 (UDP|TCP)
80 -    81 (UDP|TCP)
137 -   139 (UDP|TCP)
445 (UDP|TCP)
9091 (UDP|TCP)
14580 (UDP|TCP)
32400 (UDP|TCP)
45000 (UDP|TCP)

and to fix this, you do this:
$ nordvpn set lan-discovery enabled
Just a little heads-up: Enabling local network discovery will remove your private subnets from the allowlist.

LAN Discovery is set to 'enabled' successfully.

and then restart weewx
$ sudo service weewx restart

and this fixed it for me!
